# Excel TODAY() function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, spreadsheet

I have two tables in excel

The first table is called Oranges, it shows where the oranges were produced and where they were exported to:

[image: oranges table]

The second table is supposed to show the total oranges shipped to locations based on the date, here is my desired result:

[image: Year To Date]

I have the following formula for Column2 row 4:

```
=SUMIFS(Oranges[[#Data],[Quantity]],Oranges[[#Data],[Exported To]],"=British Columbia",Oranges[[#Data],[Date Shipped]],"<TODAY()")
```

TODAY() = 29/1/2016

This gives me a total of 0 when it should give 1750

I have formatted the "Date Shipped" Column as a date but it still doesnt work.

Any ideas why this is returning 0?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the quotes in `"<TODAY()"`. Currently, this is treating the entire thing as a string and never evaluates `TODAY()`. The correct way to write this should be:

`"<"&TODAY()`

As the `TODAY()` is now outside of the quotes, it is treated as a formula rather than a string. It is then appended to "<", which, hopefully, should give you the result you wanted.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much. Adjusting to excel syntax is interesting as a programmer lol